# Remove banner about missing Google API keys

Tags: chromium

Recently I installed Chromium as a Google-free alternative to Chrome.

Now every time I run Chromium it shows me a yellow banner telling me that I need to set some Google API keys.
I realize that I won't be able to use any Google features without these keys, but since I want a Google-free experience I don't mind that at all.

So my question is, is there a way that I can remove this annoying banner?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Windows:

Open cmd or powershell with the the same user/permissions you want to use chrome with (e.g. you shouldn't launch as admin if you are running on your default user).

Then enter these three lines:

```
setx GOOGLE_API_KEY "no"
setx GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID "no"
setx GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET "no"
```

Restart Chrome and the banner should be gone.

Answer (score 1):

For linux you can add into ~/.bashrc

```
 export GOOGLE_API_KEY="no"
 export GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID="no"
 export GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET="no"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).